# data passing in android

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to have transfer item list page(main page). For main page, list of item, quantity and button "add new item".  List of item and quantity will get from another page(Apper when click on "add new item" button. For another page, it will be list of item that are from database. when click on item ask the quantity as dialog box(How many quantity do you want?) and then click ok on dialog box. it will take to main page. and show on main page as item and quantity.
How can i do it for that? Any idea for that?

ListItem.java

```
@Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position, long id) {
        // Save our current position
        mCurCheckPosition = position;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), position+ "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // Return selected item to caller
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),TransferList.class);
        intent.putExtra("StrName", position);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
    }
```

How to pass and show this data to Main Page?
Can you help me to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is worded in such a way that I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do, but I think the use of `SQLite` might help you.

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html
This is a great tutorial that will help you get your feet wet in `SQLite`.